# Ajax jquery POST implementation in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to make a  web app. but I don't want to use jquery for ajax. Here's the jquery implementation of this.

```
    $('#btn-predict').click(function () {
            var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
    
            // Show loading animation
            $(this).hide();
            $('.loader').show();
    
            // Make prediction by calling api /predict
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/predict',
                data: form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    // Get and display the result
                    $('.loader').hide();
                    $('#result').fadeIn(600);
                    $('#result').text(' Result:  ' + data);
                    console.log('Result:  ' + data);
                },
            });
        });
```

I want to convert this into vanilla javascript. So, I have tried this..

```
var btnPredict = document.getElementById('btn-predict')
    btnPredict .addEventListener('click', function (){

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload-file'))

        // Show loading animation
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn-predict')
        btn.style.display = 'none'

        var loader = document.querySelector('.loader')
        loader.style.display = 'block'

        // Make prediction by calling api /predict
        var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
        r.open("POST", "/predict",  true);
        r.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
            if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200){
                // Get and display the result
                var loader = document.querySelector('.loader')
                loader.style.display = 'none'
                var result = document.querySelector('#result')
                fadeIn(result,600)   // fadeIn is defined below 
                result.textContent = 'Result: '+ data
                console.log('Result: '+ data)
            }
        }
        r.send(formData)
    })
```

But this gives me   **Result : [Object Event]**
What's wrong in my code? What is the javascript equivalent of

```
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false
```

Comment: Suggest you use the more modern and more robust `fetch()` api rather than `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Okay.. I will inform you  if this help me out .. @ControlAltDel

Comment: @charlietfl ... okay..I will try to use `fetch()` .. Actually I'm a complete beginner ...

Comment: *"but I don't want to use jquery for ajax"* If the rest of your page uses jQuery, there is no reason to avoid jQuery for Ajax.

Comment: @Tomalak  oh I see.. my words are a little bit ambiguous.. Actually I don't want to use jquery at all.

Comment: @ControlAltDel  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest This does answer my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @charlietfl  It's working!...thanks al lot.